# bootstrap selectpicker not showing options

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying to use  bootstrap `selectpicker` to use a selectable list with a search field on the top. But is not working as expected:

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" multiple data-max-options="1">
    <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">GasSanto</option>
    <option data-tokens="mustard">TeixeiraeSantos</option>
    <option data-tokens="frosting">Gavedra</option>
</select>
```

But in the browser it just appears like this

[image]

I'm loading the required files like this:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-select.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">      

<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.3.2.1.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-select.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have them up to date, in the static folder..

Comment: Your code works as expected when relying on Bootstrap 3.x and jQuery 1.x (which is what Bootstrap Select supports).  If you try to use Bootstrap 4.x and jQuery 3.x I get the results you're experiencing.  *Edit*: The developer has a beta version that supports BS4: https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/releases/tag/v1.13.0-beta

Comment: @Robert is right. But good news, Bootstrap 4 support has officially been added in [v1.13.0](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/releases/tag/v1.13.0)!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you got the correct Jquery/Bootstrap installed. See the example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" multiple data-max-options="1">
            <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">GasSanto</option>
            <option data-tokens="mustard">TeixeiraeSantos</option>
            <option data-tokens="frosting">Gavedra</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm loading those files with django static load:
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.3.2.1.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Can you verify those files get loaded in a webbrowser with developer tools?